# Get List of VM Full Folder Paths through PowerCLI

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I'm using vSphere 6.0 and the newest PowerCLI. I want to get the name of a VM and it's path. Something like get-vm myvmware | get-folderpath

I've tried a couple solutions found online, but either they don't work at all or they get all the VMs. I have a list of VMs I need to feed to this to get their paths

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could do something like this with a function. It doesn't appear that VMware has anything like this built-in.

```
Function Get-VMFolderPath {

    param([string]$VMFolderId)

    $Folders = [system.collections.arraylist]::new()
    $tracker = Get-Folder -Id $VMFolderId
    $Obj = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{FolderName = $tracker.Name; FolderID = $tracker.Id}
    $null = $Folders.add($Obj)

    while ($tracker) {
       if ($tracker.parent.type) {
        $tracker = (Get-Folder -Id $tracker.parentId)
        $Obj = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{FolderName = $tracker.Name; FolderID = $tracker.Id}
        $null = $Folders.add($Obj)
           }
           else {
        $Obj = [pscustomobject][ordered]@{FolderName = $tracker.parent.name; FolderID = $tracker.parentId}
        $null = $Folders.add($Obj)
            $tracker = $null
       }
    }
    $Folders.Reverse()
    $Folders.FolderName -join "/"
}

$VM = Get-VM "VM Name"
Get-VMFolderPath $VM.Folder.Id
```

This will list the folder path starting from the Data Center container down to the VM folder that contains the VM.